# Ubuntu randomly crashing on old laptop

Tags: freeze, crash

I have an old laptop, on which I installed Ubuntu. Sometimes, when I'm coding on it, the system freezes and the only solution is to disconnect the power source. Using journalctl, I found the following messages on the last crash:

```
jul 13 22:49:46 jpjunho1 NetworkManager[760]: <info>  [1657763386.8840] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.169
jul 13 22:50:43 jpjunho1 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_MP_EXEC - TP 0 MP 0: 00000008 [TIMEOUT] at 07fa98 warp 0, opcode 82030a10 82040a14
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: We don't know what Ubuntu product you're talking about, so our ability to offer meaningful advice is somewhat limited. Logs should tell you the issue, but we have no idea as to your chosen software stack (*release, desktop, apps*), your hardware (*available RAM etc including if you've chosen apps that share resources or you've chosen to waste resources*) etc. You need to disconnect power source??  So switching to text terminal isn't available, neither direct commands to kernel (ie. SysRq) doesn't work - ie. kernel panic??  Are you sure?

Comment: Does that happen only when you are coding? What Ubuntu are you using? If it is an old laptop, then you should not be using Ubuntu 13 or later as they require significantly more RAM to operate. Can you go to terminal when it freezes by pressing ctrl+alt+f3? You can also following the instructions stated here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: I guess on hardware failure, in best case a loose cooler on the GPU or to much dust on the cooler or the airflow. In worst case broken RAM which is used by the GPU.